# ¿"También" puede llevar dos comas?

Tags: gramática

Necesito saber cual de las dos opciones es la correcta

> Las ballenas, también, tienen nariz.

o

> Las ballenas también tienen nariz.

Comment: Yo me quedaría con la segunda. Entiendo que la primera también sería válida para reflejar una pausa en un dialogo que implique, por ejemplo, enumeración de seres que tienen nariz. "Los perros tienen nariz. Los gatos tienen nariz. Las ballenas, también, tienen nariz." O algo así.

Comment: Agregaría que, sin comas, "también" se refiere al objeto, no al sujeto, ej. Las ballenas tienen ojos. Las ballenas también tienen nariz (= además de ojos).